# How to prevent spans from hiding bar charts?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting a bar graphic and horizontal spans with this code:

```
fig = plt.figure('Graphic', figsize=(20,15), dpi=400)
     
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.75])
data.plot('DATE',["PP"],kind='bar',color='black', fontsize = 15.0,ax=ax1,alpha=1)
data.plot('DATE',['PP'],kind='line',marker='*',style=['--'],linewidth=1,color='gray', ms=5,ax=ax1)

ax1.axhspan(0, 1, facecolor='lightyellow', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(1, 1.5, facecolor='yellow', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(1.5, 2, facecolor='lime', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(2, 3.5, facecolor='green', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(0, -1, facecolor='bisque', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(-1, -1.5, facecolor='orange', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(-1.5, -2, facecolor='pink', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(-2, -3.5, facecolor='red', alpha=1)
```

The issue is that spans are hiding the Bar graphic. I would like to be able to visualize the spans with the bar graphs. Both with alpha=1. I don't want to reduce the alpha values.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

I am displaying the image with axhspans with alpha=1 covering the bar charts.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed two things that needed to change.

1. When you use pandas line and bar plots with X-axis being dates, there was/is a bug. Refer to this [link](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10761#issuecomment-128671523). The workaround used here is what was there. Using matplotlib plot instead of pandas helped resolve this.
2. Refer to [zorder](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html). You can specify the order of the various components (line plot, bar, spans) to tell it what will come on top of what. Higher the `zorder`, the higher the plot will be. I have used 1 for the spans zorder, 2 for the bar plot zorder and 2 for line plot.

Updated code is below. See if this helps.

```
fig = plt.figure('Graphic', figsize=(20,15), dpi=400)

ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.75])
data.plot('DATE',["PP"],kind='bar',color='black', fontsize = 15.0,ax=ax1,alpha=1, zorder=2) ## Added zorder

# Changed to matplotlib, increased linewidth to 3 so you can see it and zorder=3
ax1.plot(data[['PP']], marker='*',ls='--',linewidth=3,color='gray', ms=5, zorder=3)

## All zorder = 0
ax1.axhspan(0, 1, facecolor='lightyellow', alpha=1, zorder=1)
ax1.axhspan(1, 1.5, facecolor='yellow', alpha=1, zorder=1)
ax1.axhspan(1.5, 2, facecolor='lime', alpha=1, zorder=1)
ax1.axhspan(2, 3.5, facecolor='green', alpha=1, zorder=1)
ax1.axhspan(0, -1, facecolor='bisque', alpha=1, zorder=1)
ax1.axhspan(-1, -1.5, facecolor='orange', alpha=1, zorder=1)
ax1.axhspan(-1.5, -2, facecolor='pink', alpha=1, zorder=1)
ax1.axhspan(-2, -3.5, facecolor='red', alpha=1, zorder=1)
```

**Plot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The order of display in the pandas plot is not adjustable, so I guess we have to deal with it in matplotlib. ax is set up with a line chart and horizontal fill, and a bar chart is added as a second axis. Then I get the order of the line chart, add 1 to the value of the line chart, and set the display order to the bar chart. Since no data was provided, stock price data was used as a sample.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
data = yf.download("AAPL", start="2022-06-01", end="2022-09-01")
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure('Graphic', figsize=(10,7.5), dpi=100)
     
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.75])
ax1.plot(data.index, data['Close'], marker='*', linestyle='--', linewidth=1, color='gray', ms=5)

ax1.axhspan(170, 180, facecolor='lightyellow', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(160, 170, facecolor='yellow', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(150, 160, facecolor='lime', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(145, 150, facecolor='green', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(140, 145, facecolor='bisque', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(135, 140, facecolor='orange', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(130, 135, facecolor='pink', alpha=1)
ax1.axhspan(120, 130, facecolor='red', alpha=1)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.bar(x=data.index, height=data['Volume'], color='black')
ax2.set_zorder(ax1.get_zorder()+1)
ax2.set_frame_on(False)

ax1.set_ylim(120, 180)
plt.show()
```

[image]